# Android dependency conflict

Tags: android, gradle

I've got a message:

> All android support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification. Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0.

It appears in this line of code:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

UPDATE: My dependencies are following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Please share full build.gradle file and also project level build.gradle file

Comment: sorry for duplicate. marked answer solved my problem. thanx